# is it possible to access variable in watch() function vue

Tags: vue.js

I want to access variable `asd` in my watch() function and clear `asd` interval I tried code below but it's not working timer goes below 0 so any possible solutions?

```js
  methods:{
    testing(){
        this.sTimer--;
      if(this.sTimer == 0){
        clearInterval(this.asd)
      }
    }
},
watch(){
 var asd = setInterval(() => this.testing(), 1000);
}
```

Comment: What are you watching? you must pass an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `watcher` is not watching any thing! You need to provide an data item for which it watches for it's changes

```
watch: {
  item: function (newItem, oldItem) {
    console.log(oldItem + " changed to: " + newItem);
  }
},
```

Also, you might want to add your `asd` variable to `data` section.

```
data() {
  return{
    asd = null;
  }
},
methods: {
    testing(){
        this.sTimer--;
      if(this.sTimer == 0){
        clearInterval(this.asd)
      }
    }
},
watch() {
 item: function (newItem, oldItem) {
   this.asd = setInterval(() => this.testing(), 1000);
 }
}
```